# Where does Windows 10 keep the information for Pinned Start icons?

Tags: backup, windows-10, restore, start-menu, default-profile

I am looking for the how and where Windows 10 remembers what is pinned for individual profiles Start Menu.

I have been looking to create a modified default user profile in Windows 10 Enterprise and one of the most important things to change is the default Pins for the Start Menu. I have read different articles that explain Windows 8/8.1 and how to create backups and defaults for it but things seem to have changed for Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can run (WinKey+R) "shell:User Pinned" and it will open an file explorer window with the folder that holds (TaskBar) the pinned shortcuts.

Here you have a useful list of other folders:
http://winaero.com/blog/list-of-shell-commands-in-windows-10/

Hope this helps.